# Is piecex good site to sell my web template?

Tags: freelance-websites

I want to sell web template.Wondering is piecex a good site to sell my template or not?Can I sell my template through it?

Answer (score 0):

Piecex is a platform where you can either Sell your own code/script or purchase one for yourself. So if you think that your design can attract customers and your web template is good enough so that people will purchase it, then go for it.